# How to choose maximum count using 'Having'

Tags: mysql, sql

```
INSERT INTO  accounts (account_id, type_id, client_id, created,close_date,last_activity_date, a_status, branch_id,
      open_emp_id, avail_balance, pending_balance) 
      VALUES
    (233355103, 'SAV',1651 ,'2015-07-30' ,NULL ,'2015-06-30', 'ACTIVE' ,1111 , 184167702 ,1500.00 ,1500.00 ),
    (233355234, 'CD',1651 ,'2006-03-30' ,NULL ,'2018-06-30', 'ACTIVE' ,2221 ,184167713 ,1500.00 ,1500.00 ),
    (233777234, 'SAV',1888 ,'2015-03-30' ,NULL ,'2019-06-30', 'ACTIVE' ,3331 ,233755101 ,1500.00 ,1500.00 ),
    (233778884, 'CD',2343 ,'2015-03-30' ,NULL ,'2019-06-30' , 'ACTIVE' ,4441 ,239961844 ,1500.00 ,1500.00 ),...

    INSERT INTO employee 
     (emp_id, first_name, last_name, start_date, manager_id, dept_id, job_id, branch_id)
    VALUES 
    (218803412, 'Michael', 'Smith', '2010-06-22',NULL,  234, 'AD_PRES', 1111),
    (122212562, 'Susan', 'Barker', '2010-09-12', 218803412, 234, 'AD_VP', 1111),
    (225748882, 'Alexander', 'Peter', '2010-07-03',122212562 , 334, 'IT_MANG', 1111),
    (190538847, 'Robert', 'Tyler', '2010-02-09',218803412, 234, 'AC_MGR', 1111),..
```

Currently there are many accounts that are made by the same employees (ex)Michael can make 2 accounts, Susan can make 5 accounts, etc). accounts and employee table are linked by accounts.open_emp_id = employee.emp_id. Goal is to 1. count the number of accounts made by each employee 2. Find one or more employee with the highest number of accounts.

Hope I made the situation better. Thank you

Comment: I don't understand the difference between 1 and 2. So if an employee made 30 accounts, then wouldn't that also be the max number? What does the desired output look like?

Comment: shae table and data,  and also a the complete error message

Comment: Do you need (1) and (2) in a single query or just the result of (2)?

Comment: Ah sorry for making it confusing, just the result of 2. There are many different employees making different number of accounts (some make 1 or 2 while the maximum was 5).

Comment: And what to do on a tie? If two employees both have the maximum number of accounts?

Comment: You can't use `GROUP BY` in the subquery. The subquery has to return just one number so you can compare it with `counts =`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel As you can see I am a beginner...I saw the database and there was no tie

Comment: Please describe your table. Post some sample data and the expected result. That will avoid anwers based on wrong assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer myself, and I think this one is easier to understand:

```
SELECT open_emp_id, COUNT(account_id) AS how_many FROM accounts
GROUP BY open_emp_id HAVING COUNT(account_id) =
(SELECT COUNT(account_id) FROM accounts GROUP BY open_emp_id ORDER BY COUNT(account_id) DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a CTE to get the counts by employee. Then get the maximum of that.

```
WITH counts AS (
    SELECT open_emp_id, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM accounts
    GROUP BY open_emp_id
)

SELECT c.*
FROM counts AS C
WHERE c.count = (SELECT MAX(count) FROM counts)
```

Comment: If I were to add a part where I count the number of accounts that each employee made, how do I do that?

Comment: Isn't that what `COUNT(*)` does?

Comment: I think there is no 'counts' collumn. It's already aggregated. See the original version of the question.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel You think the OP thinks that `WHERE count =` assigns a value to `count` rather than comparing it?

Comment: Yes - there's no counts column

Comment: To explain it in code - I think they need either `order by count(*) desc limit 1` or `having count(*) = (select count(*) ... order by count(*) desc limit  1)`. But it's on OP to write a clear question.

Answer (score 1):

I know its long and not the best query out there but it works.

```
SELECT open_emp_id, COUNT(account_id) Accounts FROM accounts GROUP BY open_emp_id HAVING COUNT(account_id) = (SELECT MAX(counts) FROM (SELECT (SELECT COUNT(account_id) FROM accounts innerTable WHERE outerTable.open_emp_id = innerTable.open_emp_id) counts FROM accounts outerTable) GroupByWithSubQuery);
```

Comment: It got exactly what I needed, but it's long so I'm trying to interpret it. Thank you - may I keep the question open to see if there are more concise codes? Thank you once again

Comment: @SoyoonMoon It's okay, no problem.